# Compositing masking is there a way to improve the performance of the viewer updating

Tags: compositing-nodes

Trying to mask, working on a 4K plate, whenever I select or move a mask point the viewer wants to update every single time. A lot of the time, usually 7 out of 10 times the plate blinks out, the view zooms out/in a little hence moving your mask point you are currently holding with the mouse button and then doesn't show up at all so you can't see what you've done. You have to then either select a different mask point or scrub the timeline (thus cancelling the mask move you've just done), then it might decide to load the plate back or you have to repeat the select another mask point again. It's next to impossible to roto like this, is there a solution? I've tried changing the chunk sizes under performance and leave the edit on high setting, open CL is enabled all the other four check boxes are off (this is in the side N panel in the compositor view).

FYI i'm only working on one layer but it has around 6 masks active on it.